# Layout issue related to "Relative Layout"

Tags: android

Hi I'm making my first android program 'a calculator'. I was using the relative layout instead linear layout and I found some problems when it running it in the emulator.

1) the frame has not centered in the screen. 
2) Once it is in the landscape mode, the numbers again goes to left side instead of centering it.

I tried many ways but still the problem remains same.

[image]
[image]

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:background="#fbf8c9"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7"
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8"
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9"
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button12" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="*"
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/"
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10"
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

please someone kindly help me in solving this issue..

Comment: Use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` for your inner RelativeLayout width and height. While keeping `match_parent` for the outer one. So it will be as big as the sum of its children widths and heights (plus margins) and therefore it can be centered in its parent.

Comment: Thanks it worked.... Applying gravity as given in another answer worked.... Anything which is better?

Comment: Why down voting? I got the answer after many searches? Next time its better to mention the reason as well before just down voting and leaving. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#fbf8c9"
        android:editable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly what I said in my comment. But without the explanation of WHY does it work.

Comment: Frank N Stein, You're absolutely right.  But When I opened there were no answers. Just tried to correct it. and posted it. Didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this in your xml:
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is common issue in RelativeLayout you must be use LinearLayout